# Is there a way to combine these 2 VB.Net extension methods into a single one?

Tags: vb.net, embed, extension-methods, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am chaining two extension methods together to process and embed YouTube videos in page. The reason is, up until just a few moments ago, embedding was handled with a short code. I just now added embedding support via the oEmbed.dll from CodePlex. The first method below is the new one, the 2nd is the short code one which I need for backwards compatibility so I don't break previous posts.

So is there a way to combine these 2 into one method so I don't have to chain them together?

```
<Extension>
Public Function EmbedYoutubeVideos(input As String) As String
    Dim regex__1 As String = "http(?:s?)://(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com/watch\?v=|\.be/)([\w\-]+)(&(amp;)?[\w\?=‌​]*)?"
    Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(input, regex__1)
    If matches.Count = 0 Then
        Return input
    End If
    Dim width As Int32 = 620
    Dim height As Int32 = 349
    Dim objYouTube As New WillStrohl.API.oEmbed.Providers.YouTube
    Dim strVideo As String
    For i As Integer = 0 To matches.Count - 1
        Dim mediaFile As String = matches(i).Value
        strVideo = objYouTube.GetVideo(matches(i).Value, width, height)
        Return input.Replace(matches(i).Value, strVideo)
    Next
End Function

<Extension>
Public Function ConvertYouTubeShortCode(text As String) As String
    Dim regex__1 As String = "\[youtube:.*?\]"
    Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(text, regex__1)
    If matches.Count = 0 Then
        Return text
    End If
    Dim width As Int32 = 620
    Dim height As Int32 = 349
    Dim BaseURL As String = "http://www.youtube.com/v/"
    For i As Integer = 0 To matches.Count - 1
        Dim length As Int32 = "[youtube:".Length
        Dim mediaFile As String = matches(i).Value.Substring(length, matches(i).Value.Length - length - 1)
        Dim player As String = "<div class=""video-container"">"
             <iframe width=""{2}"" height=""{3}"" src=""{4}{1}"" 
              frameborder=""0""    allowfullscreen></iframe></div>"
        Return text.Replace(matches(i).Value, [String].Format(player, i, mediaFile, width, height, BaseURL))
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: I'll ask here as well.. what is the point of the loops.. you're returning on the first iteration.. when I is still 0..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following perhaps?

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
Public Function ConvertYouTubeShortCode(text As String, Optional ByVal IsEmbed As boolean = false) As String
    Dim regex__1 As String
    Dim matches As MatchCollection
    Dim width As Int32 = 620
    Dim height As Int32 = 349  
    Dim mediaFile As String

    If (IsEmbed) Then
        regex__1 = "http(?:s?)://(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com/watch\?v=|\.be/)([\w\-]+)(&(amp;)?[\w\?=‌​]*)?"
        matches = Regex.Matches(text, regex__1)

        If matches.Count = 0 Then Return text

        Dim objYouTube As New WillStrohl.API.oEmbed.Providers.YouTube
        Dim strVideo As String  
        For i As Integer = 0 To matches.Count - 1 Step 1
            mediaFile = matches(i).Value
            strVideo = objYouTube.GetVideo(matches(i).Value, width, height)
            Return text.Replace(matches(i).Value, strVideo)
        Next      
    Else
        regex__1 = "\[youtube:.*?\]"
        matches = Regex.Matches(text, regex__1)

        If matches.Count = 0 Then Return text

        Dim BaseURL As String = "http://www.youtube.com/v/"
        Dim length As Int32
        Dim player As String         
        For i As Integer = 0 To matches.Count - 1 Step 1
            length = "[youtube:".Length
            mediaFile = matches(i).Value.Substring(length, matches(i).Value.Length - length - 1)
            player = "<div class=""video-container""><iframe width=""{2}"" height=""{3}"" src=""{4}{1}"" frameborder=""0"" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>"
            Return text.Replace(matches(i).Value, [String].Format(player, i, mediaFile, width, height, BaseURL))
        Next
    End If
End Function
```

**EDIT:** What is the point of the Loops when you return on the first iteration?